# ASP.NET Core: Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint on table may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: entity-framework

I want to create databse (SQL server) from CodeFist approach. When I run `dotnet ef database update` I get error:

```
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Tasks_JobComments_Users_OwnerId' on table 'Tasks_JobComments' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

I found some topics (mostly of them are old). I found thread in [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3815), but this code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    foreach (var relationship in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().SelectMany(e => e.GetForeignKeys()))
    {
        relationship.DeleteBehavior = DeleteBehavior.Restrict;
    }
```

does not help.
I want to prevent any delete if there are foreign keys. I think that upper code do just that, but how can I bypass error when using `dotnet ef database update`?
I am using .NETCoreApp version 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

your migration folder contains a migration file that is being used for creating your database. in this file search for the constraint that causes the problems. (in your case "FK_Tasks_JobComments_Users_OwnerId") and change

```
onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

to

```
onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
```

How it can be fixed / avoided within the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)` method I didn't figure out until now.